# Is Captain Janeway's Locutus description correct?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, borg

I have never seen [the relevant](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Best_of_Both_Worlds_(episode)) [episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Best_of_Both_Worlds,_Part_II_(episode)) but from the references to it, made in other Star Trek parts, I've got the clear meaning that [Locutus of Borg](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Locutus_of_Borg) was **actually a typical Borg drone**, crafted by assimilation of Captain Jean-Luc Picard.

If that is true, how then can Captain Janeway picture him, in the beginning of [Scorpion. Part II](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Scorpion,_Part_II_(episode)) episode using words similar to: "*Pick a representative. Like you did to Captain Jean-Luc Picard, when you turned him into Locutus*".

So, what exactly was Locutus? Was he a *full-picture* Borg drone or just the *Borg representative*?

Comment: “I have never seen the relevant episode” — I think I’ve spotted the core problem, right here.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite No, you haven't. This question was asked 2,5+ year ago. Since that I have already watched mentioned episode and haven't changed my mind. The question remains. Janeway's description of Picard being Locutus is incorrect in my opinion.

Comment: Okay. From [the transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/174.htm): “BORG: [To Picard] Your archaic cultures are authority driven. To facilitate our introduction into your societies, it has been decided that a human voice will speak for us in all communications. You have been chosen to be that voice.” Did you miss that bit?

Comment: OK, you have convinced me. Then post this as an answer, so I can upvote it and maybe even accept, if I find it better than current answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Locutus literally means "he who speaks." *The Best of Both Worlds* had Locutus as a drone specifically created with communication in mind; bear in mind that the Borg usually simply attacked, and that it was unusual for them to face an enemy they bothered to negotiate with, even if the Borg's idea of negotiating was "surrender or die."

From [the transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/174.htm):

> BORG: [To Picard] Your archaic cultures are authority driven. To facilitate our introduction into your societies, it has been decided that a human voice will speak for us in all communications. You have been chosen to be that voice.

*Star Trek: First Contact* further establishes that the Borg Queen wanted an equal, an individual among the Borg to be her mate, and that Picard was to be that equal. He was certainly still a Borg drone, but he was far from the average drone.

Comment: First Contact retconned rather than established.

Comment: @lucasbachmann hasn't every ST retconned that which came before it?

Comment: @PeterM So **that** is what is meant by going *where noone has gone before*, thanks ;)